# Table not updating in single select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, sql-insert

i have a temporary table which i need to update, the first row is updated but the second row updates as null , please help

```
declare @T Table
(
 ID int,
 Name nvarchar(20),
 rownum int 
)

insert into @T(ID,rownum)
select ID, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by id) from testtabel4

select * from testtabel4

update @t
set Name=case when rownum>1 then (select top 1 Name from @T x where x.rownum=(y.rownum-1))
 else 'first' end
from @t y

select * from @T
```

and here the definition of testtabel4

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testtabel4](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

and here is the output

```
ID  Name
1   first
2   NULL
```

Comment: Why are you doing this; `y.rownum-1`? That looks like the problem in your `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

You are only inserting two columns in the `@T`:

```
insert into @T (ID, rownum)
    select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id) 
    from testtabel4;
```

You are not inserting `name` so it is `NULL` on all rows.  Hence, the `then` part of the `case` expression will always be `NULL`.

Comment: if we have n no of rows in a table and the column A of row n-1 is updated by a select statement,now based on the n-1 column A ,i need to update the column A of nth column in the same select statement which is updating the column A of n-1 row. The select statement is selecting the columns from other table. Hope this clarifies what i want to achieve.Is it possible?

Comment: kindly guide a Dev

Comment: @CuriousDev . . . This is calculating the new `rownum` by assigning a sequence number to each row.  I don't see that recursion is needed.

Comment: that is not the solution of my problem,kindly check above

Comment: the table is same ,updating and selecting

Comment: i wrongly specify the selection of table is different from the current table ,its the same table,updating and selecting the same table

Answer (score 0):

I think your update would be better written with `lag()` and an updateable CTE.

```
with cte as (
    select name, lag(name, 1, 'first') over(order by rownum) lag_name
    from @t
)
update cte set name = lag_name
```

With this technique at hand, it is plain to see that don't actually need to feed the table first, then insert into it. You can do both at once, like so:

```
insert into @t (id, name, rownum)
select 
    id, 
    lag(name, 1, 'first') over(order by id),
    row_number() over(order by id) 
from testtabel4
```

I am not sure that you even need `rownum` column anymore, unless it is needed for some other purpose.

Comment: i need to update the next row based on the comparison of previous and the current row column,say i have two columns ,i updated the first column in the first row ,then based on this value i need to updated the next column,it is not readable ,i tried the above code but same result.is it related to some locking,say the column that is marked for updation is not readable?

Comment: the solution works only when the column u are updating must have value other than NULL

Comment: all cells must have value

Comment: it is not updatable if the value is null